# How to check if ElasticSearch index exists and is ready?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I check if a index exists AND is ready for use in ElasticSearch?

We currently check if "indexA" exists by running a query which selects some documents. If the query don't return any hits we assume that "indexA" don't exist, and create the index (fresh install). The problem is that our application starts faster than ElasticSearch when the server reboots, and we get two duplicate "indexA" because the search for doucments in "indexA" fails when ElasticSearch is starting up.. (I guess the index is not ready yet)

There is a method: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-exists.html - is this guaranteed to return "true" for "indexA", even when ES is starting up and the index is not ready yet?

Or should I use the "status"-method, specify indexname, and check if all shards have status "STARTED"?

Or should I use this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-recovery.html  Can ElasticSearch go into "recovery-mode"? When does this happen and how should we handle it?

Or should I look into "CatHealth"? .Epoc?

Comment: When you say _ready_, do you just mean ready to start searching? Reading into your question, it sounds like you'd like to know the status of the cluster, which you can do with `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html You can pass a query string param `wait_for_status=green` that will wait until the cluster is in the given status (or until the timeout expires, 30 seconds by default)

Comment: Yes I mean ready to start searching/indexing. I want my application to "wait" until ElasticSearch is ready. I experimented a little, and if we query ES for documents before it's ready it just return zero documents found. Your suggestion sound correct and seems to work (although our cluster only reaches status yellow)

Comment: So I think I got a solution when starting my application, I just wait for status yellow or green, which means no shards are initializing. Please add your comment as answer and I'll mark it as answered.  But could it be a problem if the cluster starts reallocating shards? Does ES work like normal when allocating?

Comment: Is ES still initializing shards for the index or relocating them for the index, or you have unassigned shards, when in yellow status? I'd recommend installing Marvel - https://www.elastic.co/products/marvel or ElasticHQ - http://www.elastichq.org/ as a UI for monitoring your cluster. Shards cannot be used whilst they're initializing (or relocating, IIRC)

Comment: How many nodes and shards are you running with?

Comment: Currently we only have one node, and can't get to status green since ES cannot allocate replica-shards (?). My index is showing 5 allocated shards and 5 unallocated shards. I'm using "head-plugin" as a simple gui for monitoring, .

Comment: OK, that explains the yellow status. You have 5 primary shards (the default), and all 5 shards are located on the one node. Since you have number of replicas set to 1, but have only one node in the cluster, Elasticsearch will not assign the replica shards to the same node that has all the primaries (a bit like keeping your hard disk backup on your hard disk!) Either add another node to the cluster, and ES will distribute the primary and replica shards amongst nodes, or set number of replicas to 0 (I would recommend having at least one replica for production for backup and failover however)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say *ready*, do you just mean ready to start searching?

Reading into your question, it sounds like you'd like to know the status of the cluster, which you can do with the [Cluster Health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true
```

You can pass a query string param `wait_for_status=green` that will wait until the cluster is in the given status (or until the timeout expires, 30 seconds by default).

Based on your comments in the question, the cluster is in yellow status because there are 5 unassigned shards; when running with the default configuration, Elasticsearch creates 5 primary shards and 1 replica (i.e. a replica shard for each primary shard). Since there is only one node in the cluster, the replica shards will remain unassigned as Elasticsearch will not locate them on the same node that contains all the primary shards as this will not provide any redundancy. Adding another node to the cluster will cause Elasticsearch to relocate 2 of the primary shards onto the new node along with 3 replicas, and 2 replicas onto the original node. With this distribution, a node can go down but no data will be lost. Adding another node will change the status to green, although you will be able to use the cluster in yellow status.

If you're going to be using this cluster in production, I strongly recommend having at least 2 nodes (*ideally* on separate machines) so you have at least one replica.